# Passing Variables in PHP to subpages

Tags: php, variables, scope, var

Hello I know method to passing vars to other including page like:

```
$_GET['pages']

if (isset($_GET['pages']))
{
    $Page = addslashes ( $_GET['pages'] );
    include('pages/'.$Page.'.php');
}
```

If I want go to sub page i must type `?pages=hee` etc, if I type by hand `mywebsite/pages/hee.php` there are no variables send to hee.php and i got errors . Is there other method to achieve passing vars not by this global `$_GET?`

Comment: You have too many single quotes in that `include` statement

Comment: uh, if you go to `http://example.com/pages/hee.php` directly, there's no variables because you didn't provide any... and note that addslashes() in this context is utterly useless. you're not doing sql, and the characters escaped by addslashes() won't do anything for include().

Comment: how to provide that -  [link](http://example.com/pages/hee.php) will get all variables from [link](http://example.com/index.php) ?

Comment: Instead of $_GET. You can use superglobal $_POST or $_SESSION.

Comment: so how to achieve that i type 'http://example.com/pages/hee.php' and how to use $_POST to get all vars

Comment: There is `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE`, `$_SESSION` (if you set one up). http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php it's not really clear what you are looking for here. If you load `mywebsite/pages/hee.php` you want `index.php` to be loaded with `$_GET['pages']` having the value of `hee`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP sessions for this:

```
//page
$_SESSION['yourvar'] = $var1;
//On subpage
$var1 = $_SESSION['yourvar'];
```

> Session support in PHP consists of a way to preserve certain data
>   across subsequent accesses.

Or you can also use cookies to do your job:

```
//page
$_COOKIE['yourvar'] = $var1;
//On subpage
$var1 = $_COOKIE['yourvar'];
```

> Cookies are a mechanism for storing data in the remote browser and
>   thus tracking or identifying return users

Comment: give m ur mail hangout anything u have i will pay 5$ for help its complicated

Comment: It`s ok , I do not need the money, you can initiate a chat option here if you  want to discuss this.

Comment: no idea, if it is not too much , you can describe your problem details in the question itself

Comment: https://mega.nz/#!Hw8UXLwA!UGJ8k0_JxKc0J9W5kDeL-9A1qLZZaBXp6bNm8D64lWw there are files u will understand what  i want